# While sorting my product collection automatically shuffeling

Tags: magento2.2, product-collection, product-sorting

**For Magento 2.2 I'm using:-**

```
$categoryId=185;

$ct = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId); 
        $collections = $ct->getProductCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) 
                     ->addAttributeToSort('sort_value', 'DESC');

    echo "<pre>Test" ; print_r($collections->getData());exit;
```

& getting 15 records.

but currently, **'sort_value' attribute is empty for all 15 records**. & whenever I'm refreshing pages each time collection is shuffling while the same script is giving fixed collection for Magento 1.

I needed fixed collection means whenever I refreshed the page it should remain same.

For a product, I assigned sort_value=10 just for testing & now this product is coming always on top.while rest of the 14 products(having empty sort_value) are shuffling.

**Note:-1** the type of sort_value is price.

**2-** I've used  addAttributeToSort('sort_value', 'DESC'); on product listing & it gives expected result.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you checked the attribute is filterable ?

Comment: Add this query  secondary soring  `addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'DESC')`   after `addAttributeToSort('sort_value', 'DESC')`  as secondary shorting

Comment: @Elavarasan, thanks for the reply! yes this is filterable.i already explained in the post.

Comment: @Amit,thanks for the reply!  same thing is working for product listing.actually according to my requirement i can't use addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'DESC') because i'm only sorting product listing by using only 'sort_value'.so according to product listing i've to show 4 neighbour(based on some condition) products on the product detail page.